# A new example question in the tour page?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

The [tour](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/tour) page gives a good introduction how the site works and new users tend to know more about the site. It is helpful for a new user if they read the tour badge.

We still have the default "How to prevent unicorns from eating daisies" as our example question. It would be very nice if we had our own question in the tour page.

[A post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/163947/357396) on mother meta gives some of the criteria for an example question.

> The example question should
>
> - be accessible to the intended audience (perhaps even to the newest and most naive person in that audience)
> - be judged at least decent by the community (positive score)
> - have more than one answer which are also judged acceptable (again positive score)

and its [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/163948/357396) gives one more.

> Apparently the posts have to be short, with at least two short answers (<=400 chars). They also shouldn't have any crazy formatting.

I think there are some good posts which are fit for the tour page. Adding them to the page would make a user feel more friendly with the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few possible candidates?:

- [What is Seitan? How do I get it?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/38/what-is-seitan-how-do-i-get-it)
- [Is "starter" in yogurt vegetarian?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/790/is-starter-in-yogurt-vegetarian)
- [How can I get the same rise in baked goods when I replace cow milk with almond milk?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/550/how-can-i-get-the-same-rise-in-baked-goods-when-i-replace-cow-milk-with-almond-mv) (cleaning up the comments could be good - are those comments really useful now?)
- [Does eating in a mixed buffet drive up meat demand, even if I only eat vegetarian dishes?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/870/does-eating-in-a-mixed-buffet-drive-up-meat-demand-even-if-i-only-eat-vegetaria)
- [Weight gain tips for a vegan diet?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/160/weight-gain-tips-for-a-vegan-diet)

Moderator Edit:

"[Weight gain tips for a vegan diet?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/160/weight-gain-tips-for-a-vegan-diet)" is now our example question on the tour page.

Comment: The thing is there should be one than one upvoted answers with no complicated markdown and should have an accepted answer. The last one fits very well.

Comment: Actually, none of these questions work... >_>.  See [this meta question for details](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163947/what-determines-the-questions-available-for-selection-in-the-tour-page).

Comment: @Riker (excuse double ping :S) according to [that query](http://data.stackexchange.com/vegetarianism/query/92078/possible-about-questions) the only qualifying question we have is [this one](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/98/do-any-major-religions-promote-or-require-a-vegetarian-diet)

Comment: @Zanna indeed.  That's definitely true, since that's the only option we get if I click the edit tour button. :(  We can always try to clean up some of the other questions, like the weight gain tips one.

Answer (score 0):

As of now (2022), the tour question has reverted to the SE template "How to prevent unicorns from eating my daisies?" (which is ... ironically, closer to being on-topic here than on most sites!) and [Weight gain tips for a vegan diet?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/160/weight-gain-tips-for-a-vegan-diet) (mentioned in Zanna's answer) is no longer available as an option to put on the tour.

There are currently three **possible** choices for the Tour question, according to the SE built-in restrictions:

- [Is wine considered vegan?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/1416/is-wine-considered-vegan)
- [Are meat substitutes necessary for a vegetarian lifestyle?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/416/are-meat-substitutes-necessary-for-a-vegetarian-lifestyle)
- [Do any major religions promote or require a vegetarian diet?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/98/do-any-major-religions-promote-or-require-a-vegetarian-diet)

Note that the two answers that will appear on the Tour preview must be **short and without any formatting like blockquotes etc.**, which means it won't be the highest-voted answers for any of the above three options. Probably we can bring [Weight gain tips for a vegan diet?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/160/weight-gain-tips-for-a-vegan-diet) back into the required restrictions by removing the bold-text formatting from the accepted answer, and then the top two answers would be able to appear in the Tour as before. Or we can choose one of the three questions bullet-pointed above. What do people think?